# How to access class const using class property of another class

Tags: php, oop

I've run into this a few times and can't find a solution. What I'm trying to do is store a class name ( including namespace if relevant ) in a class property and call a const using `$this->property::CLASS_CONST;`
The only way I've figured out how to do this is by using a local variable instead of class property. Anyone know why this is, or if there is any way around it? My example code is below:

```
$o = new B();

$o->summon();

class A {

  CONST VALUE = 'HELLO WORLD';

}

class B {

  protected $className = 'A';

  public function summon() {

    //works
    $class = $this->className;
    echo $class::VALUE;

    //doesn't work
    echo $this->className::VALUE;
  }

}
```

Comment: Because you don't have direct access to $this->className from your public method

Comment: Possible duplicate [13313459](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313459/why-i-cant-access-static-property-of-a-class-when-class-is-a-dynamic-property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP's `constant`:

```
$o = new B();

$o->summon();

class A {

  CONST VALUE = 'HELLO WORLD';

}

class B {

  protected $className = 'A';

  public function summon() {

    // works
    $class = $this->className;
    echo $class::VALUE;

    // doesn't work
    echo $this->className::VALUE;

    // works
    echo constant($this->className . '::VALUE');
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this method.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that this not working would be by design.  As the semantics are not clear.

Are you trying to get as you intend the property and use that as the class name.

Or are you looking to get the value of the property `className::VALUE`.  Since you could have a variable property.

It also can be confusing to read.  Imagine in your case that you had your property named `A` then it would read `echo $this->A::VALUE;`  What would you expect to have happen?